# Tomcat 9 add webapi at runtime

Tags: tomcat, web.xml, webapi, tomcat9

I don't know if it's possibile . When I create a webapi I must declare in web.xml the related class/url

```
  <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>myServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/myServlet.htm</url-pattern>
        <!-- WebApi -->
        <url-pattern>/Timbrature2/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/Timbrature2.json/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/Timbrature2.xml/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/Timbrature/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/Timbrature.json/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/Timbrature.xml/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/TimbratureMobile/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/TimbratureMobile.json/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/TimbratureMobile.xml/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/$metadata</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

but if my webapp load from jars dynamic code can I add a "new" class to be used as a REST endpoint?

Read Apache documentation, tryied various configurations but nothing

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you are trying to do. Are you asking if it's possible to add another API call (e.g. with a different URL pattern) without modifying `web,.xml`?

Comment: Yes exactly... i've understood that a webapi url pattern must be registered in web.xml.. can i add another url at rendimento?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want one servlet to handle everything, you can register it to broad URL patterns like

```
<url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
```

It's worth reading the [Servlet Specification](https://javaee.github.io/servlet-spec/downloads/servlet-4.0/servlet-4_0_FINAL.pdf) and specifically section 12.2 (in the 4.0 release of the spec) which covers "Specification of Mappings". This describes the kinds of `url-mapping`s which are possible.

Another option is to use `@WebServlet` annotations in your code (covered in section 8.1.1 of the above document) to establish a mapping from within your code. I have a preference for the declarative mapping found in `web.xml` because all mappings are co-located rather than spread out across arbitrary source files whose source may not always be available.